# Neo4j SET error - Variable not defined

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

When I write the following Neo4j Cypher query in Java:

```
propertiesQuery = new StringBuilder();
propertiesQuery.append("MATCH (si)-[r]->(so) WHERE r.name = $rName  ");
propertiesQuery.append("SET ");
String g = "None";
propertiesQuery.append("r.flow");
propertiesQuery.append("=");
propertiesQuery.append(g);
```

and execute the **propertiesQuery** statement, it gives me the following error:

> org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Variable 'None' not defined

when in reality **None** is the value of the string variable **g**. Can somebody please explain the error here ( I already initialized the required parameters - so that is not the error)?

Comment: Maybe you have to append not just `"None"`, but something like `"\"None\""` or `'None'`? I think the query language needs to know it is a value and not a variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cypher query needs to specify a string literal.

Try changing:

```
String g = "None";
```

to:

```
String g = "'None'";
```